# Sumif for Specialcellsvisible not working and summing in total and not visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs

> Sumif for Specialcellsvisible not working and summing in total and not
> visible cells only

My Code is:-

```
ws2.Cells(i, J).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws1.Range("G:G"), ws2.Cells(i, 2), ws1.Range("K:K"))
```

Any help?

Comment: Where in there is there a condition for visible cells only?

Comment: i applied condition for visible cells in ws1.range("K:K").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible) for sum range but it gives error 1004 unable to get Sumif properties

Comment: That is because `specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)` returns multiple ranges and sumif requires a single range.

Comment: any solution to get the sum of visible rows.?

Comment: Maybe `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal` but I'm not sure if it'll work with a criterion like SUMIFS.